# Can I recover a deleted .m file from an .asv file?

Tags: usb, data-recovery, matlab

I have just used *Disk Drill* from the cleverfiles website to recover some MATLAB files that I have accidentally deleted  from a USB drive.

Some of the .m files I recovered are perfectly fine, but the ones I am most interested in recovering present the following form when I open them on MATLAB:

[image]

Does this mean that the file is completely unrecoverable? Or could perhaps the .asv version of the recovered .m file be used to recover the original content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the particular `.m` to something else. Then rename the `.asv` to `.m`.  If this is damaged as well, then it is unlikely that you can recover.

As soon as you write to a drive after deleting files, parts of the files can get overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it did not change anything on the file, and the files are permanently lost.